# Automatically populate Matrix Rows

Tags: matrix

Is there a way to automatically populate Matrix rows with channel entries with a custom status?

Comment: or to pull data from a playa entry in a matrix field?

Comment: Hey Niall, Matrix rows don't have a status specifically, that's part of the entry, unless you've made a status column.  You could certainly make a column for a Playa relationship in Matrix though.  More details with what you actually want to accomplish and have thus far tried would help us help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Playa (and EE relationships) work in that they *link* to an entry rather than *pull in from* that entry. Obviously you don't want to have duplicate data in your system and a relationship prevents that whilst keeping context. What you describe should be possible but using Playa to establish the relationship and then creating a new column in your Matrix field entitled 'Status' and using a select box field (I'd recommend [P&T Field Pack](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pt-field-pack)) to provide your own status options per entry.